# SQL Server 2014 selecting random rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

When I run the query (see below) it generates random 8 000 rows.

```
SELECT top 8000
ind_int_code as 'Individual Type',
ind_first_name as 'First Name',
ind_last_name as 'Last Name',
cst_recno as 'Member ID',
cst_eml_address_dn as 'Email Address',
adr_city as 'City',
adr_state as 'State' ,
adr_country as 'Country',
cst_org_name_dn as 'Company',
cst_ixo_title_dn as 'Job Title',
mem_member_type as 'Member Type'
FROM 
co_individual  WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN co_individual_ext  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON ind_cst_key_ext=ind_cst_key 
JOIN co_customer  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON cst_key=ind_cst_key and ind_delete_flag=0
and ind_deceased_flag=0 
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON cst_cxa_key=cxa_key 
LEFT JOIN co_address  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON adr_key=cxa_adr_key 
LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON cst_key=mem_cst_key 
WHERE mem_member_type Is Null AND adr_country = N'UNITED STATES' AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 AND ind_key_leader_flag_ext != 1 AND ind_int_code != N'Staff' AND ind_int_code != N'Spouse' AND ind_int_code != N'Press'
ORDER BY NEWID(),ind_last_name
```

If you look at the sample data, I am interested in the column called mem_member_type as 'Member Type' in vw_client_uli_member_type table (In this column, there is around 10 different Member types). 
What I am trying to accomplish is that I need number of rows(see below) for specific Member Types only(Member Type column in data sample)

```
3500 rows of Associate Member
1680 rows of Full Public Agency
1200 rows of Associate Sustaining
1620 rows of Full Member
```

My result set should look like my data sample:

```
8000 total rows distributed between Member types: 
3500 rows of Associate member
1680 rows of Full Public Agency
1200 rows of Associate Sustaining
1620 rows of Full Member
```

I hope this helps and apologize for not including enough info in the previous questions.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg4Ex.jpg)

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Comment: Be careful splattering that NOLOCK hint all over the place. It carries a lot more baggage than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  nd_int_code as [Individual Type],
            ind_first_name as [First Name],
            ind_last_name as [Last Name],
            cst_recno as [Member ID],
            cst_eml_address_dn as [Email Address],
            adr_city as City,
            adr_state as [State],
            adr_country as Country,
            cst_org_name_dn as Company,
            cst_ixo_title_dn as [Job Title],
            mem_member_type as [Member Type],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mem_member_type ORDER BY NEWID()) as RN
    FROM co_individual WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN co_individual_ext WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON ind_cst_key_ext = ind_cst_key 
    INNER JOIN co_customer WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON cst_key = ind_cst_key 
        AND ind_delete_flag=0
        AND ind_deceased_flag=0 
    LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON cst_cxa_key = cxa_key 
    LEFT JOIN co_address WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON adr_key = cxa_adr_key 
    LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON cst_key = mem_cst_key 
    WHERE mem_member_type IS NULL 
    AND adr_country = N'UNITED STATES' 
    AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 
    AND ind_key_leader_flag_ext != 1 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Staff' 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Spouse' 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Press'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE ([Member Type]= 'Associate Member' AND RN <= 3500)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Full Public Agency' AND RN <= 1680)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Associate Sustaining' AND RN <= 1200)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Full Member' AND RN <= 1620);
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. When I run the code above, it gives me an error message: Invalid column name 'mem_member_type' in the part where I specify number of rows: Invalid column name 'mem_member_type'.

Comment: Thank you @Lamak. Now, I keep getting empty result set only with the headings. I tried to lower the number of rows but it doesn't affect the results.

Comment: Problem solved. It was on my end. Thank you very much.